# How do I create a Lua Table in C++, and pass it to a Lua function?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, lua, lua-table

In C++, I have a `map<string, string>`, containing an unknown number of entries.  How can I pass this to a Lua function, so that the Lua function can use the data as a table?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you want a real lua table:

```
lua_newtable(L);
int top = lua_gettop(L);

for (std::map::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it) {
    const char* key = it->first.c_str();
    const char* value = it->second.c_str();
    lua_pushlstring(L, key, it->first.size());
    lua_pushlstring(L, value, it->second.size());
    lua_settable(L, top);
}
```

with the right types for your map substituted in..

Answer (score 5):

A couple options...

1. Copy the map into a new Lua table, and pass the Lua table.
2. Create a [proxy table](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.html) that directs reads and writes through a metatable's `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods

The drawback to (1) is all the copying, of course.

The drawback to (2) is that `pairs()` won't work on the proxy table

A discussion of fixes to Lua for generalized `pairs` is [in the wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/GeneralizedPairsAndIpairs) and [this mailing list thread](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-02/msg00423.html). Generalized `pairs` is expected for [Lua 5.2](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaFiveTwo)

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to add an iterator function to the metatable that can be used just like pairs() for tables.

Comment: i usually do option 2; unless the table is small and there's lots of requests to a mostly read-only table.