# C++ & Lua, push Lua table as argument

Tags: c++, function, lua, lua-table

I'm integrating Lua in C++, and now I have this table that behaves as a 'class', and for some functions it needs a 'self' argument, which actually is the table. The Lua code:

```
a = {
numb = 5,

create = function(a)
    print(a);
end,

increment = function(self)
                            --self.numb = 6;
                            print(self.numb);
end,

decrement = function(self,i)
                            self.numb = self.numb-i;
                            print(self.numb);
end
};
b = a;
```

And the C++ bit to call the functions (I've got Lua running in C++)

```
luaL_openlibs(L);

luaL_dofile (L,"main.lua");

lua_getglobal(L, "a");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "increment");

string arg = "a";

lua_pushliteral(L,"a");

lua_pcall(L ,1,0,0);

printf(" \nI am done with Lua in C++.\n");

lua_close(L);
```

So, how can I pass in the self argument, as a table, into the function increment?

any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you asking how to create a lua table in C++ and pass it to the function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453769/how-do-i-create-a-lua-table-in-c-and-pass-it-to-a-lua-function

Comment: No, I want to pass in a Lua table from my script, as an argument in a lua function, wich i want to call in a C++ function. So actually it is a kind of pointer to the table itselfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lua 5.1 you use [`lua_getglobal`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getglobal) to, um, get a global, like your table `a` -- you are using it to get your table just a few lines above; all you need to do is duplicate that value to pass it to your function

```
 lua_getglobal(L, "a"); // the table a is now on the stack
 lua_getfield(L, -1, "increment"); // followed by the value of a.increment

 lua_pushvalue(L,-2); // get the table a as the argument

 lua_pcall(L,1,0,0);
```

Comment: @dirkwillem click the check box next to the correct answer.  No need to put [solved] in the question title.