# std::map kind of implementation in Lua

Tags: dictionary, lua, lua-table

I have `std::map` which contains list of values associated with a Key. Actual implementation contains many such Keys. Is there a similar way in Lua Table implementation which could hold multiple values for a specific key. If so how to write and read from that table.

I referred the [How do I create a Lua Table in C++, and pass it to a Lua function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453769/how-do-i-create-a-lua-table-in-c-and-pass-it-to-a-lua-function) 
I have only access to set and get values which is on my C++ code which was written more generic and cannot create table in C++. (Third party C++ code).

All I have is I can get KeyType, Key, and Value using the

`luaState = luaL_newstate();
 lua_register(luaState, "getValue", get_value);
 lua_register(luaState, "setValue", set_value);`.

The C++ code has something like

```
typedef std::set<const char *> TValueNames;
std::map<const char *, TValueNames> keyValueList;
```

By referring to Lua document I understood I can create a table with Key as index and assign value as its data. But I need to know how to assign multiple value(data) for one Key.
https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html

The example lua script implementation is like,

```
local keyType = getValue("KeyType");
local Key = getValue("Key");
local Value = getValue("Value");
KeyValueTable = {}
KeyValueTable[Key] = Value;
```

I need to create something which could hold information like,

```
["Key1"] = {"Value1,Value2,Value3"};
["Key2"] = {"Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5"};
```

Comment: Do you need the table in LUA or C++.  In C++ you can look at a `std::multimap`.

Comment: I need table in Lua which could hold similar to std::map in C++

Comment: @kar: A `std::map` cannot hold multiple values per key. Only a `std::multimap` can do so. Your `keyValueList` is still only holding one value. It's just that this value happens to be a container that itself contains multiple things. But `map` itself is only holding a single object.

Answer (score 4):

As you know, a key in a Lua table can only refer to one value, but you can easily make that value a table to hold multiple values. To more faithfully represent the `set` in the C++ structure, we can make the values into keys in the inner table.

```
local function setValue(self, key, value)
  self[key] = self[key] or {}
  self[key][value] = true
end

local function removeValue(self, key, value)
  if type(self[key]) == 'table' then
    self[key][value] = nil
  end
end

local function checkValue(self, key, value)
  if type(self[key]) == 'table' then
    return self[key][value]
  end
end
```